# Raspberry-pi Solana errors

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, solana

Solana Raspberry Pi installation.
I am trying to install the solana tool on my Raspberry Pi.
I allready tried installing it over releases.solana... (described here: https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) but that causes error 403. Then I tried to build it from the binarys(described in the docs too) that causes the problem that The Raspberry says that something is wrong with the programm files. and now I am trying to install it (like described here:https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/) with github. But that causes this error

```
user@raspberrypi:-/solana $./cargo build
error: command failed: 'cargo': No such file or directory (os error 2)
./cargo: Missing toolchain? Installing...: 1.69.0
info: syncing channel updates for '1.69.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  1.69.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)

info: checking for self-update
error: command failed: 'cargo': No such file or directory (os error 2)
+ exec cargo +1.69.0 build
error: command failed: 'cargo': No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I tryied everything I descibed above and I want that I can do everything described in the docs(https://docs.solana.com/de/cli/install-solana-cli-tools (next docs(creating walletc etc.))).

Comment: To install from GitHub, you need to follow the instructions on the GitHub page. You need to do the first step "Install rustc, cargo and rustfmt".